# is there any third party library or any component given by Android to show images like fb feed?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, feed, android-viewholder

i got the list of images from gallery, now how to put images in single item like grid as facebook or other apps does?

[image: please check this image]

Comment: Use RecyclerView with CardView it should do the trick

Comment: please read my question properly @ItzikSamara, i am using cardview with recyclerview item..my question was to show images like grid in that particular item.

Comment: @kuldeepzala you can manage a grid recyclerview upto count 4 and mange accordingly.. I think for that no need to use any third party.

Answer (score 0):

Inside LinearLayout take 4 image view. let's call this imageview as imageView1,imageView2,imageView3, imageView4. each image view will have a height in dp or wrap content. set weight property 1 for each image view. now to show two images set the visibility of remaining image view as gone. or if you want to shows three image view set last image view visibility to gone.

Comment: @user33833787 looks doable...you just saved my day thanks.